# How to make a loop in a login-system in Java? The user should have "3 tries" to login

Tags: java, loops, authentication

I've have this assignment where I need to make a login system in Java (I'm using Eclipse as IDE).
My login system works fine, but I am missing a loop- from where it is possible for the user to "try again". I would really like if the users could have 3 tries.

Is it possible, and can anybody help me?

**This is my code:**

```
package BookingSystemPackage;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Booking_login {

public static void main(String[] args) { 

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 

    System.out.println("Enter your Social Security number in the format DDMMYY-XXXX: "); 
    String cpr; 
    cpr = input.next();

    if (cpr.length() != 11 || cpr.charAt(6) != '-') {         
        System.out.println(cpr + " You have entered a invalid social security number");
    } 

    else if (Character.isDigit(cpr.charAt(0)) 

        == false || Character.isDigit(cpr.charAt(1)) 
        == false || Character.isDigit(cpr.charAt(2)) 
        == false || Character.isDigit(cpr.charAt(3)) 
        == false || Character.isDigit(cpr.charAt(4)) 
        == false || Character.isDigit(cpr.charAt(5)) 
        == false || Character.isDigit(cpr.charAt(7)) 
        == false || Character.isDigit(cpr.charAt(8)) 
        == false || Character.isDigit(cpr.charAt(9)) 
        == false || Character.isDigit(cpr.charAt(10)) 
        == false) { 

        System.out.println("You have entered a invalid social security number");

    } 

    else { 

        System.out.println("You have entered a valid social security number");

        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        Scanner inputLogin = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please write your user name: "); 
        String UserName = inputLogin.nextLine(); 
        System.out.println("Please write your password: "); 
        String Password = inputLogin.next();

        System.out.println((validateUser(UserName,Password)) ? "You are logged in" : "You are not logged in"
    }
}


public static boolean validateUser(String UserName, String Password) { 
    String[] userNames = {"Super user", "User", "Admin", "Lucille"}; 
    String[] passwords = {"AA11" , "BB22" , "CC33", "HVORFOR!"}; 
    boolean chek = false; 
    for (int i = 0; i < userNames.length; i++) { 
        if (UserName.equals(userNames[i])) { 
            if (Password.equals(passwords [i])) { chek = true; } 
        }  
    }
    return chek;
}
```

Comment: What did you try? Hint: store the number of tries per user and reset it upon successful login.

Answer (score 1):

I would break the password checking into a separate method, that returns `true` or `false` depending on whether the user has succeeded in logging in.  Then call that method and take the appropriate action depending on the return.  So your main method might have something like

```
String password = "s3cr3t";
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean authenticated = login(password, 3, input);
if (authenticated) {
    // Do some stuff here
} else {
    System.out.println("Sorry, I can't let you do that");
}
```

and your login method might look like this.

```
public static boolean login(String password, int numberOfAttempts, Scanner input) {
    for (int attempt = 1; attempt <= numberOfAttempts; attempt++) {
        System.out.format("Attempt %d - Please type your password: ", attempt);
        String passwordEntered = input.nextLine();
        if (passwordEntered.equals(password)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you an idea:

```
int i = 0;
boolean isLoggedIn = false;
String password = "123";

while (!isLoggedIn) {
   System.out.print("Please enter your password: ");
   String input = new Scanner(System.in).next();

   if (input.equals(password)) { 
      System.out.println("Logged in!");
      isLoggedIn = true; 
   } else {
      if (i == 2) {
         System.out.println("You have tried too many times. System will now shut down.");
         System.exit(0);
      }
      System.out.println("Not logged in");
      i += 1;
   }
}
```